# Change the width and height of jQuery slider

Tags: css, jquery-ui, overriding, jquery-ui-slider

I want to change the width and height of jquery slider UI. I am using `ui-lightness` theme. I tried to override the default jquery.css by adding the following code in my style sheet.

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-horizontal { height: .6em; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  cursor: default;
}
```

But the above css has no effect. jquery.css overrides the above style and I see no change in the slider. How to override the default jquery.css styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the `!important` rule over after your `width` and `height` declaration, like so:

```
width:1em !important;
height:1em !important;
```

That should force your declaration to be read.