# How to prevent slider from stretching?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, slider

Just getting acquainted with jQuery UI. So, this is a block of code from my view:

```
<label id="min">
    5000</label>
<div id="slider">
</div>
<label id="max">
    9000</label>
```

And a part of the script:

```
    $('#slider').slider({
        animate: true,
        range: true,
        min: 5000,
        max: 9000,
        values: [5000, 9000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            //doing smth
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine, but the slider is stretched and takes the whole line. The labels are below and under it.
I expected them all to be in one line.

What should I do to achieve it?

**EDIT**

This is what I am expecting:

[image: Correct]

And this is what I have:

[image: Error]

**EDIT**

I tried to override the slider css by adding the following code to my *Site.css* file:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0.5em !important;
    height: 1.2em !important;
    cursor: default;
}
```

but nothing changed. How can I make jQuery use this css?

**Another note**: the original css looks like this:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    cursor: default;
}
```

So, is css the issue here? Or something else makes my slider stretch??

**MORE**

This is the generated html:

```
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 25.95%; width: 74.05%;">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 25.95%;">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 100%;">
    </a>
</div>
```

**At last**

I had to override `.ui-slider` class, not `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle`. That was the issue.

Rajesh Rolen- DotNet De, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width for slider.
[Change the width and height of jquery slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417955/change-the-width-and-height-of-jquery-slider)

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
width:1em !important;
height:1em !important;
 cursor: default;
}
```

http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/css-forum/200419-jquery-css-slider-width-100-problem.html

Comment: Could you give me a hint, how I can apply the declaration you show to the one I have?

Comment: I don't have `;` there, but `,`.....If I add `width: 150,` nothing changes.....If I add `width: 150 !important,`, the slider disappears at all..

Comment: did u set width:150 or 150px?.. better to write 150px.

Comment: if I add `150` nothing changes, if I add `150px` visual studio generates a warning saying that a comma is expected and the slider disappears in the resulting view

Comment: Sorry, when I add 150px, it results in no jquery ui at all

Comment: I'd say that the browser cannot process it

Comment: I tried to put the code you provided into the *Site.css* file, but still nothing changed

Comment: You could probably not catch that, but this is an asp.net mvc3 view..where should I put this css to make slider use it?

Comment: I've edited my question...Could you, please, have a look at it once more?